# Project Lombok - customise generated Setter

Tags: java, customization, lombok

Is there a way to customise the generated code for `@Setter`?

Consider the following simple class:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

      @Id private long id;

      @OneToMany
      private Set<AttributeColumn> columns = new HashSet<>();

      public void setColumns(Set<AttributeColumn> columns) {
          this.columns.clear();
          this.columns.addAll(columns);
      }
}
```

I want Lombok to generate the Setter for `columns` as I implemented it in the example above. This should only be done on classes annotated with `@Entity` and on attributes that are a `Collection`. The Setter for other attributes, in this example `id` should be generated as usual.

Is there a way to customise the generation of the Setter code depending on those criteria?

Comment: Technically, you could extend Lombok. Realistically, that's not easy. You need to understand both Eclipse and Javac tree structures, and getting Lombok to compile from source code is cumbersome too. But not impossible.

Comment: I see, I misread your question. Apologies for downvoting. If you edit your question, I'll undo it.

Comment: @maaartinus I edited the question, thanks for removing the down vote. Although it's currently not possible, I don't think that this question is useless to others. Also, thanks for the clarification of your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

---

No, there's no such feature and no plans for it.

As already stated in a comment, you could do it yourself, but it's not easy at all. Moreover, you'd have to decide to either hardcode the logic (simple but probable unusable for others) or interpret something like

```
@SetterWhen(@Or(
    @Condition(annotatedWith=Entity.class), 
    @Condition(declaredType=Collection.class)))
```

which is close to impossible to implement (as this information is unavailable when Lombok runs).

---

Currently, all you can do is to allow on suppress the generation on a per field basis. There's no possibility to generate a different setter, however
*there's a related feature: [`@Singular`](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/Singular.html)*, which may or may not help you.

Comment: This does not answer my question.

Comment: @MarcoNätlitz Now, it does.

Comment: @MarcoNätlitz Thank you for accepting. Originally, I forgot to provide an answer because there was already a comment making clear that it's not possible. Now I added some details (maybe useful for you,  maybe for someone else).